# List of similar objects - invoke different method for each element

Tags: c#, design-patterns, coding-style

I'm looking for a good practice/idea how to write a clean code for my solution.
Let's say I have class Foo:

```
public class Foo
{
    public SomeEnumType Type { get;set; }
    ....
}
```

I got a list of these elements like:

```
List<Foo> Foos
```

Now I want to iterate over my list and invoke different methods for any EnumType. For now I'm just doing something like this:

```
foreach (var x in Foos)
{
     if (x.Type == XXX)
        invoke first();
     else if (x.Type == YYY)
        invoke second();
     .....
}
```

It looks OK if i got one or two values in my TypeEnum, but unfortunately I will have about ~~30 and as I assume it will look terrible with ~~30 else. How to make it better? Does anyone have met such a problem before?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary of type `Dictionary<SomeEnumType, Action>`

```
var actions = new Dictionary<SomeEnumType, Action>()
{
    { SomeEnumType.SomeVal, ()=>{ Console.WriteLine("test"); } }
};

actions[SomeEnumType.SomeVal]();
```

Comment: Yes I know this approach, but is this a good practice? If I have to initalize such a dictionary with 30 elements won't it be considered as a bad practice? Just asking, because I was using this technique when I had about ~~4-5 elements, never for more. But I'm beginner so just asking :)